# Create a softlink for a file on two servers

Tags: unix, symbolic-link

I want to create a softlink for a file between two servers. The file is present on `server1` and a softlink should be created for it on `server2`.

Answer (score 1):

Symlinks don't work that way. If the server's filesystem that contains the actual file is mounted on the other then you can create a symlink on the other that points to the file.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to mount the filesystem from server 1 on server 2 (thorugh NFS or something similar) then create the softlink locally on server 2.